# How to select date from a select box using Capybara in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date, rspec, capybara

I'm writing a spec for a controller in Rails 3 project using RSpec and Capybara, and I want to select current date from a select box. I tried:

```
select Date.today, :from => 'Date of birth'
```

but the spec fails and I get error:

Failure/Error: select Date.today, :from => 'Date of birth'
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `to_xpath' for Mon, 18 Jul 2011:Date

How to fix it?

P.S. In view file I use simple_form_for tag and the select box is generated by code:

```
f.input :date_of_birth
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to specify the exact value as it's in the select menu in html. So if your select has values like "2011/01/01" then you need to write:

```
select '2011/01/01', :from => 'Date of birth'
```

Your code fails because you pass a date object.

Comment: It doesn't work. I get error:

Failure/Error: select '2011/07/18', :from => 'Date of birth'
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
  cannot select option, no option with text '2011/07/18' in select box 'Date of birth'

By the way, Rails generates 3 select boxes for each date part.

Comment: Then you need to select 3 options from 3 select boxes and use the same values as you see on the page.

Answer (score 26):

Had the same problem. I googled at lot and solved it this way:

1. Wrote date select macros into **/spec/request_macros.rb**
   The select_by_id method is necessary for me, because the month is dependent on the translation

   ```
   module RequestMacros
     def select_by_id(id, options = {})
       field = options[:from]
       option_xpath = "//*[@id='#{field}']/option[#{id}]"
       option_text = find(:xpath, option_xpath).text
       select option_text, :from => field
     end

     def select_date(date, options = {})
       field = options[:from]
       select date.year.to_s,   :from => "#{field}_1i"
       select_by_id date.month, :from => "#{field}_2i"
       select date.day.to_s,    :from => "#{field}_3i"  
     end
   end
   ```
2. Added them to my **/spec/spec_helper.rb**

   ```
   config.include RequestMacros, :type => :request
   ```

Now in my integration tests in **spec/requests** i can use

```
select_date attr[:birthday], :from => "user_birthday"
```

Thanks to http://jasonneylon.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/selecting-from-a-dropdown-generically-with-capybara/ and https://gist.github.com/558786 :)

Answer (score 9):

with credit to Markus Hartmair for an excellent solution, I prefer to use labels as selectors because of improved readability. So my version of his helper module is:

```
module SelectDateHelper
  def select_date(date, options = {})
    field = options[:from]
    base_id = find(:xpath, ".//label[contains(.,'#{field}')]")[:for]
    year, month, day = date.split(',')
    select year,  :from => "#{base_id}_1i"
    select month, :from => "#{base_id}_2i"
    select day,   :from => "#{base_id}_3i"
  end
end
```

call it like this:

```
select_date "2012,Jan,1", :from => "From date"
```

Comment: I had to use `find(:xpath, ".//label[contains(.,'#{field}')]")[:for][0..-4]` and `Date::MONTHNAMES[date.month]`

Answer (score 9):

I found a clean solution for rspec and capybara to test using date and time select methods, where in your HTML you use a datetime select or date select. This works with Rails 4, RSpec 3.1 and Capybara 2.4.4.

Say in your HTML form you have the following:

```
<%= f.datetime_select(:start_date, {default: DateTime.now, prompt: {day: 'Choose day', month: "Choose month", year: "Choose year"}}, {class: "date-select"}) %>
```

the DateTime Select View helper will create 5 select fields with ids such as `id="modelname_start_date_1i"`, where the id the is appended with 1i, 2i, 3i, 4i, 5i. By default Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute. If you change the order of the fields, make sure to change the feature helper below.

1) Create a Feature Helper for dates and times helpers

**spec/support/helpers/date_time_select_helpers.rb**

```
module Features
  module DateTimeSelectHelpers

    def select_date_and_time(date, options = {})
      field = options[:from]
      select date.strftime('%Y'),  :from => "#{field}_1i" #year
      select date.strftime('%B'),  :from => "#{field}_2i" #month
      select date.strftime('%-d'), :from => "#{field}_3i" #day 
      select date.strftime('%H'),  :from => "#{field}_4i" #hour
      select date.strftime('%M'),  :from => "#{field}_5i" #minute
    end

    def select_date(date, options = {})
      field = options[:from]
      select date.strftime('%Y'),  :from => "#{field}_1i" #year
      select date.strftime('%B'),  :from => "#{field}_2i" #month
      select date.strftime('%-d'), :from => "#{field}_3i" #day 
    end
  end
end
```

Note that for the day I use `%-d` that gives you a non-padded numeric value (i.e. 4) instead of `%d` that has a zero-padded numeric value (i.e. 04). Check [the date formats with strftime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime)

2) You then need to include your date and time helpers methods in **spec/support/helpers.rb** so you can use them in any spec file.

```
require 'support/helpers/date_time_select_helpers'
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Features::DateTimeSelectHelpers, type: :feature
end
```

3) In your Spec file you can call your helper. For example:

```
feature 'New Post' do
  scenario 'Add a post' do
    visit new_post_path
    fill_in "post[name]", with: "My post"
    select_date_and_time(2.days.from_now, from:"post_start_date")
    click_button "Submit"
    expect(page).to have_content "Your post was successfully saved"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7):

A slight adaption of Markus's answer:

```
def select_date(date, options = {})  
  raise ArgumentError, 'from is a required option' if options[:from].blank?
  field = options[:from].to_s
  select date.year.to_s,               :from => "#{field}_1i"
  select Date::MONTHNAMES[date.month], :from => "#{field}_2i"
  select date.day.to_s,                :from => "#{field}_3i"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Dylan for pointing it out, but in case anyone is looking for the cucumber version, you can use this:

```
select_date("Date of birth", :with => "1/1/2011")
```

For more information, see [select_date](http://rubydoc.info/github/cucumber/cucumber-rails/master/Cucumber/Rails/Capybara/SelectDatesAndTimes#select_date-instance_method).

Comment: This is a link to the cucumber method.  The question is asking about using capybara with rspec.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following Formtastic code renders Rails default date selector:

```
= f.input :born_on, end_year: Time.now.year, start_year: 60.years.ago.year
```

In your spec, break the date into separate calls to each individual select tag:

```
select '1956', from: 'person_born_on_1i'
select 'July', from: 'person_born_on_2i'
select '9', from: 'person_born_on_3i'
```

I don't like that this code is so aware of the HTML, but it does work with the versions of gems at this time.

Gems:

- Capybara 2.1.0
- Formtastic 2.2.1
- Rails 3.2.13
- RSpec 2.13.0

Answer (score 1):

In my particular situation, I'm adding potentially multiple date select fields to the page with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` functionality.  This means, I'm not sure what the full `id` or `name` of the fields are going to be.

Here's the solution I came up with in case it helps anyone else Googling this:

I'm wrapping the date select field in a container div with a class:

```
<div class='date-of-birth-container'>
  <%= f.date_select :date_of_birth %>
</div>
```

Then in my feature spec:

```
within '.date-of-birth-container' do
  find("option[value='1']", text: 'January').select_option
  find("option[value='1']", text: '1').select_option
  find("option[value='1955']").select_option
end
```

Here's a helper method I wrote for it:

```
def select_date_within_css_selector(date, css_selector)
  month_name = Date::MONTHNAMES.fetch(date.month)
  within css_selector do
    find("option[value='#{date.month}']", text: month_name).select_option
    find("option[value='#{date.day}']", text: date.day.to_s).select_option
    find("option[value='#{date.year}']").select_option
  end
end
```

Then using the helper:

```
select_date_within_css_selector(Date.new(1955, 1, 1), '.date-of-birth-container')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, using a date_field:

```
fill_in "Date", with: DateTime.now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Rails 4**, in case somebody gets to this question without being limited to Rails 3.

```
  select '2020',  from: 'field_name_{}_1i'
  select 'January',  from: 'field_name_{}_2i'
  select '1', from: 'field_name_{}_3i'
```

You can of course extract this to a helper and make it dynamic.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this one has been sufficiently covered, but see [Capybara's docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/c/capybara-rails-2-2-0.4.1.1/Capybara/Node/Actions.html#method-i-select) for an official answer. You can select by name, id, or label text.