# Ruby: Make a selection from a drop-down list box

Tags: ruby, xpath, capybara

I am writing scripts in Ruby that supports Capybara. I will have to select a value from a dropdown list box and I am using "xpath" to find the element and make the selection.

The code is given below:

```
<select class="sortOrder fsm textCatalogTitleBlack" style="width: 150px;">
                                    <option value="/all-products/?sort=popularity&dir=desc"> Sản phẩm ưa chuộng </option>
                                    <option value="/all-products/?sort=name&dir=asc"> Tên </option>
                                    <option selected="selected" value="/all-products/?sort=price&dir=asc"> Giá  </option>
                                    <option value="/all-products/?sort=brand&dir=asc"> Thương hiệu </option>
                                    <option value="/all-products/?sort=latest arrival&dir=desc"> Mới nhất </option>
                                    <option value="/all-products/?sort=discount&dir=desc"> Giảm giá </option>
                            </select>
```

I will need to select "Giá" from the above list-box.

I have written the code as

```
 find(:xpath, "//select[@class='sortOrder.fsm.textCatalogTitleBlack']/option[@text=' Giá  ']").click
```

Result:

```
Unable to find xpath "//select[@class='sortOrder.fsm.textCatalogTitleBlack']/option[@text=' Giá  ']" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

Please help. Is there any problem with the syntax?

Comment: Look at thin question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729786/how-to-select-date-from-a-select-box-using-capybara-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `class` attribute in your HTML is space delimited, but you have made it period-delimited in your XPath expression. XPath has no special awareness of `class` attributes, and does not use CSS syntax for them.

Switch to using spaces to match the value exactly, or else [match only a particular part of the attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/xpath-how-to-match-attributes-that-contain-a-certain-string).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works when classes are delimited with spaces.