# Can't select date with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a model called Club, which has the following fields:

```
name (string)
creation (date)
```

In my form, however, instead of showing creation, I want to show Foundation Date in the label, so I have this in my View:

```
 <div class="fields">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.label :creation, 'Foundation date' %>
    <%= f.date_select :creation %>
 </div>
```

And in my test I have the following:

```
 scenario "User creates a club with a creation date" do
    sign_in
    visit new_club_path
    fill_in 'Name', :with => 'Unió Esportiva'
    select '1952/01/01', :from => 'Creation'
  end
```

And I get:

```
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find select box "Creation"
```

The rendered HTML looks like this (for the select boxes):

```
<select id="club_creation_1i" name="club[creation(1i)]">
...
</select>
<select id="club_creation_2i" name="club[creation(2i)]">
...
</select>
<select id="club_creation_3i" name="club[creation(3i)]">
...
</select>
```

What am I missing? According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729786/how-to-select-date-from-a-select-box-using-capybara-in-rails-3) I don't need to select each box independently:

**EDIT**: I have to say that I tried using 'Creation' because when trying to use the label 'Foundation date' as:

```
select '1952/01/01', :from => 'Foundation date'
```

I would get the exact same error. However, if I select the boxes independently, such as:

```
select '1952', :from => 'club_creation_1i'
select '1', :from => 'club_creation_2i'
select '1', :from => 'club_creation_3i'
```

It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method

You can select a select box via it's name, label, or ID - 'Creation' is none of those things.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I should have said that I tried with the label before 'Foundation date' and it didn't work either.

Comment: The answer you linked to does not say you don't need to select each box independently - I suggest reading the comments on the answer.