# How to select a date in a Rails date_field form helper using Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec2, form-helpers, datefield

I have a reservation search form that contains the following date_field helper:

```
<%= date_field(:reservation, :arrival_date) %>
```

How do I select a specific date for this date_field tag using Capybara?

I tried `select "2014-01-01", from: "reservation_arrival_date"` in my spec but I get a `Capybara::ElementNotFound:` error when running the spec.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at this?

 - <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729786/how-to-select-date-from-a-select-box-using-capybara-in-rails-3>

Comment: @user880828 Yes I did and I tried the answers, the date_field tag doesn't involve i1, i2, and i3 segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of finding a way to click and select a date in the date_field tag, I instead did the following:

```
page.find('#reservation_arrival_date').set("2014-01-01")
```

This works really well and I find this approach very simple. But I'm not sure how "awkward" this may seem for an integration test.

Answer (score 10):

As stated in [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-date_field), `date_field` will not yield a `<select>` tag but an `<input type='date'>` this is why you cannot use `Capybara::Node::Actions#select`.

Instead just treat it as a regular input field:

```
fill_in "reservation_arrival_date", with: "2014/01/01"
```

Comment: I had to write the date as "2014-01-01" for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

In 2020:

```
fill_in :reservation_arrival_date, with: '2020-01-01'
```

Answer (score -1):

In 2023:

```
fill_in "Reservation arrival date", with: Date.today
```